# Mocking a method which returns Page interface

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a method which I need to write unit test case. The method returns a `Page` type.

How can I mock this method?

Method:

```
public Page<Company> findAllCompany( final Pageable pageable )
{
    return companyRepository.findAllByIsActiveTrue(pageable);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `when(companyRepository.findAllByIsActiveTrue(pageable)).thenReturn(your_mock_page_object);`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use a  `Mock` reponse or an actual response and then use `when`, e.g.:

```
Page<Company> companies = Mockito.mock(Page.class);
Mockito.when(companyRepository.findAllByIsActiveTrue(pageable)).thenReturn(companies);
```

Or, just instantiate the class:

```
List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
Page<Company> pagedResponse = new PageImpl(companies);
Mockito.when(companyRepository.findAllByIsActiveTrue(pagedResponse)).thenReturn(pagedResponse);
```

Comment: What is `pageable` in this context? The repository method findAllCompany has access to it, but the test don't. I would want to mock that `Pageable pageable` parameter too, along with `Page` return type.

Comment: @DarshanMehta - Could you pls guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135373/optional-cannot-be-returned-by-stream-in-mockito-test-classes ?

Comment: will it give a page where nothing is there? then why to use?